# Printing a string of similar characters

Tags: java, string, design-patterns, methods, sequence

Without using a loop, how to print a sequence of similar characters? the number
of such characters will be according to my wish.
ie.

****** ( 6 stars)

********(or 8 stars)

is there any string function to do this? can printf be of any help?

Comment: create one String ********************************************** and print substrings. (0, 5) (0, 6), ...

Comment: As of I am aware, no there's no such function readily available, you need to write yourself. BTW why you don't need loop?

Comment: @Simz It's homework :) (note: I'm not the asker)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `recursion` to do the same thing ,

```
printStar(int x)
{
   if(x > 0)
   {
     System.out.print("*");
     printStar(x-1);
   }
}
```

And Call `printStar(6)` to print it 6 times

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion here.

**Example :**

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printString(5);
    }

    public static void printString(int occurance) {
        if(occurance > 0) {
            System.out.print("*");
            printString(--occurance);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT : != would make an infinite loop if the input is negative (even if it doesn't make sense to do so)

Answer (score 0):

`StringUtils` has some methods like below link

[Commons Lang StringUtils.repeat()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#repeat(java.lang.String,%20int))

The code example is given below

```
String star = "*";
String repeatStar = StringUtils.repeat(star, 6);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[20];
Arrays.fill(bytes, (byte)'*');
System.out.println(new String(bytes));
```